# BSOD Windows 7 0x000000f4 CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have recently been getting bsods. They happen randomly as far as I can tell. I have ran memcheck with no problems, I have done chkdsk and sfc/scannow with no problems too. I have been looking online for a while now with no solution, I have only gotten two so far. Here are my specs

- Intel Core i3
- Kingstion Hyper X dual channel 4 * 2
- Geforce Gtx 650
- Windows 7 Home Premium

Here is Blue Screen Viewer Info On more Recent one

- CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION
- 0x000000f4
- 6.1.7601.18409 (win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
- ntoskrnl.exe+75bc0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you take a look [at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560372(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: No i did not but my question is how to solve it? It is helpful though and seems that it was a process but all the other parameters I am clueless on, if you need them I can give them to you. Thanks

Comment: please post pictures of CPU-Z (Memory and SPD tabs): http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Here are the links 
SPD:http://imgur.com/ZNwD5Pa
MEMORY:http://imgur.com/Ul5hI4c
Thanks

Comment: the command rate 1 can be the cause. Change it in the BIOS/UEFI firmware to 2.